# Need help solving this java.io.IOError: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot

So I am trying to run a spring boot application, every time I get a message in logs that my application is running successfully on localhost, but as soon as I open the link in any browser, I get a message stating "no data send by localhost, err empty response".

When I checked the logs and I am getting the following message, I have been trying to solve this since 2 days but still no luck. That's why I am asking for help here.

I tried setting up the whole application again, even tried replacing .m2 folder but still no luck.

Error logs ->

```
17:41:15.106 [XNIO-1 task-1] ERROR io.undertow.request - UT005023: Exception handling request to /
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.io.IOError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:497) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104) ~[metrics-servlet-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:251) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:186) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl  (RequestDispatcherImpl.java:227) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:149) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequestDispatcher.forward(HeaderWriterFilter.java:172) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:497) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104) ~[metrics-servlet-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at com.amazonaws.xray.javax.servlet.AWSXRayServletFilter.doFilter(AWSXRayServletFilter.java:153) ~[aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core-2.5.0.jar:?]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at com.tacton.siemens.mdm.web.filter.QueryEncodingFilter.doFilter(QueryEncodingFilter.java:33) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269) [undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133) [undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) [undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99) [undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376) [undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels$4.run(Channels.java:998) ~[xnio-api-3.3.8.Final.jar:3.3.8.Final]
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels$4.run(Channels.java:988) ~[xnio-api-3.3.8.Final.jar:3.3.8.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.<clinit>(Channels.java:988) ~[xnio-api-3.3.8.Final.jar:3.3.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeTooLargeForBuffer(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:199) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:147) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:166) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeContent(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:129) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:45) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:522) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 129 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:231) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:126) ~[?:?]
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels$4.run(Channels.java:993) ~[xnio-api-3.3.8.Final.jar:3.3.8.Final]
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels$4.run(Channels.java:988) ~[xnio-api-3.3.8.Final.jar:3.3.8.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.<clinit>(Channels.java:988) ~[xnio-api-3.3.8.Final.jar:3.3.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeTooLargeForBuffer(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:199) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:147) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:166) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeContent(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:129) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:45) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:522) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 129 more
17:41:15.122 [XNIO-1 task-1] ERROR io.undertow.request - UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xnio.channels.Channels
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:619) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:534) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:623) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:328) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376) [undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
17:41:15.125 [XNIO-1 task-1] ERROR io.undertow.request.io - UT005090: Unexpected failure
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xnio.channels.Channels
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:201) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.close(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:266) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.closeAndDrainRequest(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:692) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletBlockingHttpExchange.close(ServletBlockingHttpExchange.java:89) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.endExchange(HttpServerExchange.java:1626) [undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:416) [undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-2.0.31.Final.jar:2.0.31.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

Comment: Looks like you are reading/writing file somewhere in code and file path not found. Can you please share more code to debug the issue?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, if it was possible I would have shared the code here as well. Can you please tell me from which file do you think the error is coming from? or what could be the possible reasons for this error.

Comment: Ok. Can you please help me with a couple of questions?                                                 1)Which Java version used in app?                                                                                2)Which application server used in app?                                                                    3)Spring Boot Version?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal yes please

Comment: @RohitAgarwal Java Version - 11, Application Server - tomcat, Spring Boot Version - v2.2.10

Comment: Thanks for sharing, looks like you are using JBOSS Wildlfly server because error codes UT005090, UT005071 present in stacktrace is related to Wildfly server issues. As you mentioned Tomcat is used as application server but I think Wildfly server is also present may be indirectly.

Comment: Can you please cross check and if possible try to remove that dependency and restart your application

Comment: @RohitAgarwal, Hi, I have checked JBoss wildfly dependency is not present in pom.xml

Comment: ok, can you please run mvn dependency:tree in your project and see if any JBoss dependency is present?

Comment: In your stacktrace io.undertow.request.io package is present and Undertow is sponsored by JBoss and is the default web server in the Wildfly Application Server.  You can read more about it here https://undertow.io/

Comment: Which URL? SHow the controller and where are your files located. There is too little information in this question to be  able to answer it.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal Hi, I have checked it we do have some JBoss dependency here but I am not sure how to remove them and will it be of help or not

Comment: Yes that’s what I was suspecting. Can you please share dependency here. Will see what is the use of that dependency.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Comment: Hi @RohitAgarwal thanks for asking, no the issue is not resolved yet, I have checked with my colleagues we all have some JBoss dependency in our codebase for us it's working fine but for one of my colleagues it's not working fine. Now, we are speculating that it could be happening because of JDK version, but still no idea

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, it's a big project it has lots of controllers in it, if it was possible I would have shared the controller here with pom.xml. You guys can help me by telling me what all scenarios will cause this error.

Comment: Hi @RohitAgarwal this is to inform the issue is resolved now. Thank you guys for helping me out, the solution to this is given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72389195/post-request-failing-with-invalid-file-path-error

Thanks Stackoverflow for saving the day.

Comment: Good to know that issue is finally resolved:)

Answer (score 0):

I have done some analysis by looking into Stacktrace and got to know that error code ***UT005090***, ***UT005023*** and ***UT005071*** are related to **Undertow** that is sponsored by JBoss and is the default web server in the **Wildfly Application Server**.

I found some articles online related to these error codes and in most of them issue was the java version.  Either the Java version was not compatible with Wildfly Application Server or JRE/JDK path was not set up properly.  I am sharing some references here, I hope it helps to fix the issue.

1. https://blog.csdn.net/qq_27954241/article/details/124671134
2. https://groups.google.com/g/wildfly/c/NdinYgKwlqo
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlSp4bah1f0
4. [Wildfly Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange on Webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517553/wildfly-undertow-request-failed-httpserverexchange-on-webservice)
5. https://developer.jboss.org/thread/273775

There could be some other reason as well that I am not able to figure out so far. Let me know if this helps or if you found a better solution.